# Aligning my unordered list / div in the center of the screen

Tags: html, css

i'm trying to align the car-showcase in the center of the screen with the list items all in line / not going to the next line. Some things I tried were doing the margin to 10% on the top and bottom which yes in theory worked but is not responsive for other screen sizes.

HTML code:

```html
    <div class="car-showcase">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <h4>Car #1</h4>
                <img class="car-model" src="assets/img/car.png">
                <br>
                <a href="#">View car</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h4>Car #2</h4>
                <img class="car-model" src="assets/img/car.png">
                <br>
                <a href="#">View car</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h4>Car #3</h4>
                <img class="car-model" src="assets/img/car.png">
                <br>
                <a href="#">View car</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

CSS code:

```css
/* Car showcase */
.car-showcase {
    padding: 0px;
}

.car-showcase ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
}

.car-showcase ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 3% 5% 0% 5%;
}

/* Car title */
.car-showcase ul li h4 {
    font-size: 20px;
}

/* View car button */
.car-showcase ul li a {
    color: white;
    background-color: #ae9595;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0.5% 10%;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.car-showcase ul li a:hover {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.719);
    padding: 2% 15%;
}

/* Car image */
.car-model {
    width: 350px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `display:flex` and align the items on the center. Also, I set the height of the `div` to `100vh` in order to align the items on the center of any screen.

```
.car-showcase {
    padding: 0px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
}
```